# Copy object from Google Cloud Store storage bucket to another bucket using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-storage

I have an Angular app that uploads images to Google Cloud Store storage bucket, named supplier-images. I want to write a function to copy an image from the storage bucket named supplier-images to another storage bucket called product-images, in the same project.

I looked at the documentation and found some code for coping objects, but it only gives examples for JAVA, Node.js and a few others, nothing for javascript or typescript (which I find quite strange). Node.js looks the most familiar, so I tried implementing it but I get a runtime error. The code I tried is

```
const storage = new Storage();

    await storage
    .bucket(sourceBucketName)
    .file(sourceFilename)
    .copy(storage.bucket(targetBucketName).file(sourceFilename));
```

I tried initializing the storage bucket using "const storage = this.storage.ref(targetBucketName);", but then the rest of my code doesn't work.

Does anyone know the correct way of copying an object from one storage bucket to another using typescript. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are no provided client APIs for copying files directly between buckets like this.  You would have to read the entire object locally in memory, then upload that to the other bucket.

I strongly suggest instead looking into writing backend code using one of the methods you already discovered, and having your client app invoke that backend to perform the copy.

Comment: Thanks Doug. In that case, I think I will write a Firestore backend cloud function and use a https (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy) call to perform the copy.